# How do I extract the Maps API Key from the keygen files?

Tags: android

I generated a Maps API key by selecting Export Android Application from Eclipse. I created a new keystore and assigned a password to it. After completion of the process I found two files in the newly created keystore...

HelloGoogleMaps.apk
roys_android_key

My question is how do I extract My certificate's MD5 fingerprint: from one or both of these files in order to Generate The API key (button bottom of form)...

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html.

I am a real newbie so please excuse me if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Use cmd :

```
cd C:\Users\Alexander\Projekte\Eclipse_Projekte\
C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "direction of your key" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 >> hash.txt
```

It depends on where your java instalation is !!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be working on this soon. Can you advise? do the two files - HelloGoogleMaps.apk and roys_android_key contain the required MD5 fingerprint? And does the command line code you specified produce this as a text file, to copy and paste, or is it not that simple?

Comment: the key is written in a text file